# devise: how to allow unauthenticated access to some pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have implemented Rails with devise authentication. As part of the process I added a "global" `before_action :authenticate_user!` in the `application_controller` that requires that all pages must be authenticated.

```
# app/controllers/application_controllers.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

How do I allow some controller#actions to be accessed without requiring the user to log in first.

This is useful when sending out mass emailings, and the email contains the link to a #show action which usually requires authentication.

Answer (score 3):

Put `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!` inside your controller to allow all actions for that controller.

You can also use the `only` and `except` keywords in combination with it to only allow or forbid specific actions.

```rb
# skips authentication only for "index" and "show"
skip_before_action :authenticate_user! only: %i[index show]

# requires authentication only for "update" and "destroy"
skip_before_action :authenticate_user! except: %i[update destroy]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the controller just mention the action that required log in:

```
 before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:new, :create, :edit]
```

For example if you have the action 'send_mail' in the controller you can accessed without log in.

Comment: I have a global before_action :authenticate_user! in the application_controller

Comment: It that case you can not access any action in any controller without log in